# TypeError: fit_generator() got an unexpected keyword argument 'samples_per_epoch'

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I tried by following code using this git repo https://github.com/priya-dwivedi/Deep-Learning/blob/master/parking_spots_detector/CNN_model_for_occupancy.ipynb
I run this code get this error

````
    ### Start training!
history_object = model_final.fit_generator(
train_generator,
samples_per_epoch = nb_train_samples,
epochs = epochs,
validation_data = validation_generator,
nb_val_samples = nb_validation_samples,
callbacks = [checkpoint, early])```

**Error**
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-c39f4720b624> in <module>
      1 ### Start training!
----> 2 history_object = model_final.fit_generator(
      3 train_generator,
      4 samples_per_epoch = nb_train_samples,
      5 epochs = epochs,

TypeError: fit_generator() got an unexpected keyword argument 'samples_per_epoch'
````

Comment: Try using `steps_per_epoch`

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using samples_per_epoch use steps_per_epoch.

```
history_object = model_final.fit_generator(
train_generator,
steps_per_epoch = nb_train_samples, # Changed line
epochs = epochs,
validation_data = validation_generator,
nb_val_samples = nb_validation_samples,
callbacks = [checkpoint, early])
```